# Android supports of Interactive whiteboard

Tags: usb-peripherals

I would like to write an app for the Interactive whiteboard using my android tv box. But i am not sure what kinds of Interactive whiteboard are support my Android TV box.

1.It seems that the interactive whiteboard uses USB interface to communicate with the host. As my Android TV box has USB port and supports most of the TVs, does it mean my Android TV box can support the interactive whiteboard which support USB?

2.If the interactive whiteboard doesn't support my android TV box, can i get its driver and write it into the ROM to support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just having a USB port isn't enough: the host device also needs to understand what *protocol* the whiteboard uses to communicate; in other words, the language the whiteboard speaks. There are a number of standard protocols, or *profiles*, for common devices such as keyboards and mice, but a whiteboard is not one of these. If the whiteboard works by pretending to be a mouse, then it might work as a mouse in Android just by plugging it in. The specs for the whiteboard should say "USB HID profile" or something like that, in that case; or if you've used it with a PC, you might already have noticed something similar.

If the whiteboard doesn't act as one of the standard profiles, you'll need the manufacturer of the device to provide drivers and user software for Android. A driver for Windows or Linux won't do. Depending on how the driver works, it might be in the form of an app you can just install the usual way, but more likely, there'll be a kernel module, and you will need to compile your own custom ROM for your device (which may not be possible for your device anyway, if other drivers for the device aren't available).